# Blue/Green Deployment, Table Cloning, and Delta live table pipelines

Tags: databricks, pipeline, delta-live-tables

this a rather complex question that addresses Databricks users only.
Let me recap a bit of the context that produced it.
In the attempt to adopt the Blue/Green deployment protocol, we found good applications of the table cloning capabilities offered by Databricks.
At every new deployment interaction, we clone the existing table into the new system while keeping the old one running.
After the new system has been validated, we update the views so that anything works with no interruption.
Well, but how do we "clone" the tables used in DLT pipelines?
Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting question. In DLTs there can be regular tables, materialized views (for batch queries) and views. I don't think cloning is an option here (at least I wouldn't be comfortable enough that everything will work properly). Also each DLT saves data to separate database so thing may be more complicated.

I would suggest an exercise to actually not clone tables but whole DLT pipeline. This would of course be very hard and long process if dataset is big, as new pipeline will need to process all data from beginning. Once new DLT is validated you may switch your views to target this new tables.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Most likely the best option is replacing the the DLT pipelines with PySpark code. The Deep clone is supposed to copy streaming statuses too, so it should do the job. It's sad because the DLT pipelines are really cool stuff.

Comment: DLTs are very cool, but I came to more and more limitations when it is combined with Unity Catalog that they are almost unusable together. Now I mostly use them only for raw data ingestion and not for any downstream tasks.